# They had been continuing to applaud for 5 minutes

Tags: past-perfect-continuous

What tense is better to use to express a process in the past "for some minutes"? For example, we have a phrase "applaud for 5 minutes". If we need to say it at this moment, it will be Present Perfect Continuous.

> They **have been continuing to applaud for 5 minutes**.

So, they will continue to do it for some time.
But if we have this situation in the past, we can't just change it to Past Perfect Continuous, can we?

> They **had been continuing to applaud for 5 minutes**.

As I understand it, there is a need for some additional action after Past Perfect Continuous, for example, "They had been continuing to applaud for 5 minutes while the actors were on the scene."

But how to express this action in the past without some additional details? What tense to use?

Comment: _Continuing to applaud_ is not very idiomatic. I think most people would say "They have been applauding/clapping for five minutes" or, better still, "The applause has lasted for five minutes" - so, in the past tense "The applause lasted  for five minutes".

Comment: @KateBunting I agree, although if you were trying to express that they had been applauding, and after some point they continued to applaud for five more minutes (say, after the performers left the stage) we might phrase it a bit differently.

Comment: Usually people would choose one or the other -- either "They kept applauding as long as the actors were on the scene." or "They applauded the actors for five minutes." When the sentence feels like it's doing too much, that's when you split it up into two sentences or more.

Comment: In practice, the example utterances here are only really relevant to non-native speakers wanting to learn about what verb forms are *possible* in English. The actual natives would simply say ***The applause lasted 5 minutes*** and leave it at that.